How to remove bathroom faucet aerator housing ring?
I need help with how to remove this recessed bathroom faucet aerator housing ring. Does anyone know how to remove the inner ring in the pics? This is the space where the aerator goes.
It looks as though there is a special tool needed to fit around this particular piece. It is circular with almost hexagon type, flat sides in between the round space. But there is not much space between the flat sections and the actual faucet.
Edit: To clarify, does anyone know of any tool out there that is made to remove this type of housing in a faucet? I have found an 1.5 aerator wrench that someone recommended, but the edges were too thick and wouldn’t fit in there as well as the size was off.



You're overthinking this. It's basically just a nut. The flats are there for a standard wrench. Size will be around 7/8". An open-end wrench is best, but an adjustable wrench will work fine if it's snugged well so it can't easily slip. In a pinch, even slip-joint pliers with wide enough jaws will do.
If it's recessed beyond flush, a needle-nose on end might turn it. Worst case scenario, epoxy a wooden dowel into it, then crank it out. Get creative.
Run some hot water to expand things if it's stubborn, or use some penetrating oil.

A wrench seems great, but unfortunately a regular one won’t fit. The piece is completely flush and the space outside it and the faucet is very minimal, not large enough to fit a wrench. It seems like there would be a tool like the aerator wrench some make, with the flat and round edges.

Are you saying that the ring with the hex flats on it is flush with the edge of the faucet?

Would something like this do for you? https://www.amazon.com/LJZXX-Spanner-Plumbing-Ratchet-Hexagon/dp/B098F4BCLK

Yes, it’s flush so nothing to grab onto but a sliver of space.

I gave you two options for that scenario. Give 'em a go.

That plumbing ratchet may work, however I’m not seeing where the size of the hex is, and how thin that metal is.

I don't think a hex socket will work. There's not enough room for the outside corners inside the faucet head. That said, if you carved notches into the outside corners for clearance it would fit. Again, get creative. This ain't quantum physics. Stop yakking at us and try something. :)

Yes, thank you, they were great options, unfortunately, neither work with a regular wrench or pliers.

Did you miss the one about epoxying a handle of sorts to it? That's a common technique.

The hex actually that Huesmann suggested seemed like a great idea and has been possibly the closest to working so far, if it was a fit in size.  Thank you for the suggestion, however, I am not looking to carve anything out or ruin the faucet.

In case it wasn't obvious, I meant to modify the tool, not the faucet.
